# Issue during Binary Installation for Drake on Ubuntu. When running the install_prereqs command I receive the error 8:

Tags: drake

Okay. I will also post this on stackoverflow and update here if I found I solution there.

I am currently trying to install Drake's binary installation for python (note I am downloading the bionic release for Ubuntu). I am following the instructions found here: https://drake.mit.edu/python_bindings.html#inside-virtualenv I have noticed once I run:

`<venv_path>/share/drake/setup/install_prereqs`

I receive the following error that states that it cannot find the bionic release.:
[Notice err 8 that states Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zedtux/naturalscrolling/ubuntu bionic Release

404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUgUl.png)

I believe this is why is subsequently cannot import pydrake. Has anyone run into this issue before? Do you have any suggestions as to why this may be the case?

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you run "sudo apt update" on the command line, you'll see the same error.  If so, your problem is not related to Drake.  The Ubuntu installation itself is broken, because it is configured to use PPA that no longer exists.

You should disable or remove that PPA; perhaps https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed is useful, or else just search "remove ubuntu ppa" and there are several suggestions.